# GWT - Gracefully detect that Tomcat is restarting

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat8

I have a enterprise GWT product that runs on Tomcat8 on a retail store's local server. I have an independent daemon running that check for and installs updates The update process consists of downloading the file, stopping Tomcat, putting the updated file in place, and restarting Tomcat.

Now, if the user has this scheduled for 2 in the morning when no one is using the app, that's fine.

But, they also have the option to go into the admin settings and manually click a button to apply the update. When they do this, I'd like to be able to put up some sort of page when someone tries to access the app saying it's upgrading, and then have the browser refresh when it's back online (if they are sitting on the temp page.)

Does Tomcat facilitate this somehow? I don't feel like GWT can, because Tomcat isn't serving it up for it to be able to do anything. My app can be installed on Windows or CentOS, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

To address your issue we can do any one of the following

1. Once user click on upgrade button start showing him some masked view. Behind this view you can write down a timer which will keep hitting some dummy serivce/rpc call from server after specific time interval. Based on the response code you can understand whether tomcat is up or not.
2. We can write down some kind of web socket. Which do above job for us and try to connect automatically once server is up and running. Using events from such socket we can hide our upgrading view and take back user to required screen.